# Why \centerline does not count the line number

Tags: line-numbering, center, lineno

I am using `\centerline` to center text, and I need to count the line numbers. I use the `lineno` package, but I found that the content contained in `\centerline` will not be included in the line number. Because I need to process latex files that have been written in batches, I want to know the reason for this situation and whether there is a way to solve it by `\renewcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{listings}
\linenumbers

\begin{document}

\centerline{This is also ok!}

\centerline{But not}

test
\\test
\\test
\\test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\centerline` shouldn't really be used in latex it's a remnant of plain TeX and doesn't follow any of the normal conventions of a latex box.

As you are using it already the simplest fix is to use `\noindent\centerline{..}` then it will be seen by the line numbering.

[image]